# Kendo Method ToDataSourceResult gives timeout exception for large number of records

Tags: kendo-grid, timeoutexception

I am using Kendo Grid as below:

```
Html.Kendo().Grid<MyViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(c => c.AutoGenerate(false))
.Filterable(f =>
{
    //coding for filteration
})
.Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
.Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
.Pageable(pager => pager
    .Refresh(true)
    //coding for pages
)
.Sortable().Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
.Scrollable(s => s.Height(450))
.Filterable()
.Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
    .Events(ev => ev.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
    .Sort(sort => { sort.Add(model => model.Date).Descending(); })
    .Filter(f => f.Add(model => model.SerialNo).IsEqualTo((this.Session["Id"] as MyModel).SerialNo)) // Applying Custom Filter
    .PageSize(10)
    .ServerOperation(true)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Controller").Data("Grid_Index_additionalData")))
 .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
 .Render();
```

Code in Controller :

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
    public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string searchBox)
    {
        IQueryable<MyViewModel> filteredResult;

        var collection1 = manager.Model1SelectAll();
        var collection2 = manager.Model2SelectAll();

        filteredResult =    from c1 in collection1
                            join c2 in collection2
                          on c1.SerialNo equals c2.SerialNo 
                              select new MyViewModel
                              {
                                  Prop1 = c1.Prop1,
                                  Prop2 = c1.Prop2,
                                  Prop3 = c1.Prop3,
                                  Prop4 = c1.Prop4,
                                  SerialNumber = c1.SerialNo,
                                  Prop5 = c2.Prop5,
                                  Prop6 = c2.Prop6
                              };

        var result = filteredResult.ToDataSourceResult(request);  
        // filteredResult is IQueryable of around 3 million records
        // filtering these on basis of request.Sorts and request.Filter will give 100 records
        // But I receive TimeOut exception here

        try
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue };
            var jsonResult = new ContentResult
            {
                Content = serializer.Serialize(result),
                ContentType = "application/json"
            };

            return jsonResult;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionService.LogException(ex);
        }
    }
```

My filteredResult contains 3 million records which gives TimeOut Exception while calling ToDataSourceResult().
Also if I try to use  filteredResult.ToList() => that gives me MemoryException.
I am unable to remove Timeout exception. Kendo says that if we pass IQueryable to ToDataSourceResult, it will handle all filtering, But in my case it gives exception.

I have tried creating my own alternative of ToDataSourceResult() by handling all request.Sorts and Filters and passign just pagesize records using

```
this.ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).OrderBy("it." + sortBy).Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1)).Take(pageSize);
```

But this way I am unable to handle all the cases of filter and make this method generic for all the grids in my project.

Comment: apologies if I have got this wrong but are you telling me you are trying to load 2.8 million records into the filteredresults variable and then applying filtering on top of that result set. If that this the case I am not surprised you are getting a memory exception or timeout. I would suggest sending the filters and sorting back to the server and provide this as part of your "sql" code. (although i am guessing you are using some form of Entity Framework behind the scenes) again another assumption here.

Comment: I am using entity framework. And ToDataSourceResult does filtering in database, so probably there is no need for me to handle a number of filters and sorts? Also there is a case when no filters are applied